# Error with install plotly-extention for jupyter lab

Tags: plotly, jupyter-lab

I tried to install the jupyterlab extension of plotly by in the terminal: `jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension`. However, I get the errors like

`resolve 'vega' in 'C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\vega-lite\build\src\compile\data'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\vega-lite\build\package.json (relative path: ./src/compile/data)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\vega-lite\build\src\compile\data\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
...`

Note: I have also installed `vega`.